# Powershell .contains() check without casesensitive

Tags: powershell, substring, string-matching

I'm having a larger foreach loop code but need to get below code executed without casesensitive.

Below code snippet returns false, how can I ignore the casesensitive .contains() and the condition as true?

```
$a='aa0855'
$b='AA0855 Sample'
$b.Contains($a)
```

Expected value is true. Above code is tried with 2 variables and it returns false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **[`.Contains()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Contains) .NET string method is indeed case-*sensitive* - *invariably* in *Windows PowerShell*, and *by default* in *PowerShell (Core) 7+***.

Thus, in ***PowerShell (Core) 7+*** you can do:

```bash
# PS 7+ only
# -> $true
$a='aa0855'; $b='AA0855 Sample'; $b.Contains($a, 'InvariantCultureIgnoreCase')
```

The second `.Contains()` argument is converted to an enumeration value of type [`StringComparison`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison?view=net-6.0); **`InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` is the same value that PowerShell's operators use by default**, i.e. a case-*insensitive* comparison that is culture-neutral (i.e. performed in the context of the [invariant culture](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).

---

In ***Windows PowerShell*** you have two options, **using PowerShell *operators***, which are case-*insensitive* by default:

- **Option A**: Use [`-like`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-like), which is [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards)-based:

```
$a='aa0855'; $b='AA0855 Sample'; $b -like "*$a*"
```

If `$a` contains characters that are *metacharacters* in the context of a wildcard expression, namely `*` and `?`, and `[` / `]`,  *escape* them, either *individually* with `` ` `` or, more simply, in the entire string with `[WildcardPattern]::Escape()`:

```
$a='aa0855'; $b='AA0855 Sample'; $b -like ('*{0}*' -f [WildcardPattern]::Escape($a))
```

- **Option B**: Use [`-match`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch), which is [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based:

```
$a='aa0855'; $b='AA0855 Sample'; $b -match $a
```

If `$a` contains characters that are *metacharacters* in the context of a regex, such as `.`, they must be *escaped*, either individually with `\`, or, more simply, in the entire string with `[regex]::Escape()`:

```
$a='aa0855'; $b='AA0855 Sample'; $b -match [regex]::Escape($a)
```

**Alternatively**, use ***different* / additional .NET APIs** that are also available in Windows PowerShell:

- **Option C**: Look for the *index* of substring `$a` in string `$b` with [`String.IndexOf()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.IndexOf), which can be done case-insensitively; return value `-1` indicates that `$a` *isn't* a substring of `$b`:

  ```
  $a='aa0855'; $b='AA0855 Sample'
  -1 -ne $b.IndexOf($a, [StringComparison]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
  ```

  - Note that in this case `[StringComparison]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`, i.e. a value of the exact parameter type must be used to unambiguously target the right method overload; the *string* shortcut, `'InvariantCultureIgnoreCase'`, would be ambiguous.
- **Option D**: *Convert both strings to lowercase* before using the (single-argument, case-sensitive) `.Contains()` overload:

  - See [js2010's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74224205/45375).

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way:

```
$a='aa0855'; $b='AA0855 Sample'; $b.ToLower().Contains($a.ToLower())

True
```